# Can I install PS3 games on an external hard drive?

Tags: ps3, hard-drive

I have a PS3 Super Slim with 12 GB of flash. I need to expand its storage to install games.

On the net, I found contrasting opinions: I know I need a disk formatted in FAT32, but I don't understand if I can install games on it or if I can only store saves and multimedia on it.

In case I have to install an internal drive, do I need something to place it in? Some type of box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't install games on external USB drives.  Games will only run off of the internal hard drive.

You can replace the internal hard drive.  It will take any standard SATA 2.5" (laptop-sized) drive.  The drive will be reformatted automatically.  See [How to upgrade your PS3 hard drive](http://www.gamespot.com/features/how-to-upgrade-your-playstation-3-hard-drive-6176090/).  I upgraded to a 1 TB drive.  It took maybe ten minutes to do the swap, but a few hours to backup before the swap and a few more to restore.

You can back up to a USB hard drive, though it takes forever.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS3#Super_Slim_model):

> In PAL regions, the 250 GB model is not available; a model with 12 GB of flash memory (CECH-4000A) is available in its place. A standalone 250 GB hard drive (CECH-ZHD1) is available to upgrade this model.

So it sounds like it didn't come with a hard drive.  From what I can tell, the Super Slim will take regular 2.5" SATA hard drives, but they take a specialized mounting bracket to install properly.

Sony is also selling everything you need in a single package, so you can just buy that if you don't want the trouble of finding the parts yourself.

Comment: 3.5''? not 2.5''? i know my PS3 doens't have an HD but only a flash, so i need a special bracket to mount the drive, thank you for the info.

Comment: Oh, derp.  Typo, sorry.